# Super + uparrow not maximizing window

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16 and using super+left/right arrow works as expected, but the super+up/down arrows don't work for maximizing/minimising the focused window (this should be a default feature of Ubuntu 18 as far as I know). How can I check why this error exists and fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the upgrade, the hotkey configuration may not be properly set.

In "Settings" under "Keyboard", "Windows" section, check to what "Maximize window" is set. If it is different than default, click the backarrow to reset to default, which should be `'<Super>Up`. If different, then set the combination yourself.

*Method using terminal*

Alternatively, directly reset the key using the command line:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize
```

If (what I do not expect) the default turns out to be different, you can explicitly set the combination with the command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize ['<Super>Up']
```

Comment: Yes, the keys were set differently (with ctrl+super), thx!